# to create a button in javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript

the name of the button is not getting displayed...
this is the code:

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.setAttribute('name','write');
button.setAttribute('class','ui-button_S40button');  
button.setAttribute('style','width: 100px;');
button.setAttribute('value','Write');  
document.getElementById("write_testi").appendChild(button);
```

Comment: can u show complete code

Comment: applying a `name` this way works fine for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/uTXBC/

Comment: Did you mix up `name` and `innerHTML` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
 button.setAttribute('text','Write');
```

or

```
button.innerHTML = 'Write';
```

Comment: The attribute `name` is something different than the buttons `innerHTML`

Comment: An HTML attribute `text` does not exist. The first example won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  var  button = document.createElement('input');
          button.type = 'button';
          button.value = 'Write';
          button.id ='Write';
          .........................
          .........................


document.getElementById("write_testi").appendChild(button);
```

Comment: Why are you creating an `input` element?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting stumped here.

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
```

Try:

```
var button = document.createElement('input');
```

Comment: @FelixKling because i din't know about that syntax of creating button.
can you explain?

Comment: `<button>` is a valid HTML element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an `input` element (see it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4VU7/)):

```
var button = document.createElement('input');
button.setAttribute('name', 'write');
button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
button.setAttribute('class', 'ui-button_S40button');
button.setAttribute('style', 'width: 100px;');
button.setAttribute('value', 'Write');
document.getElementById("write_testi").appendChild(button);
```

Or assign the `innerText` DOM attribute ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j4VU7/2/)):

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
button.setAttribute('name', 'write');
button.setAttribute('class', 'ui-button_S40button');
button.setAttribute('style', 'width: 100px;');
document.getElementById("write_testi").appendChild(button);
button.innerText="Write";
```

Comment: The standard property is `.textContent`, your example will work in IE but not in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.className = 'ui-button_S40button';
    button.style.width = '100px';
    button.innerHTML = 'Write';
    button.value = 'Write';
    button.name = 'Write';

document.getElementById("write_testi").appendChild(button);
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sXU9w/1/).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers suggest switching to `<input>` (different *Node*) or using `innerHTML` (which deviates from your pure use of DOM methods so far).

You can do this in pure DOM methods as follows.

```
button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Write'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function insertButton() {
    var button = document.createElement('input');
    button.type = 'button';
    button.setAttribute('name','write');
    button.setAttribute('class','ui-button_S40button');  
    button.setAttribute('style','width: 100px;');
    button.setAttribute('value','Write');  
    document.getElementById("write_testi").appendChild(button);
}

window.onload = insertButton;
```

Make sure `write_testi` is a `div`

If you have an existing function you call on `window.onload`, put code inside `insertButton` function in there.